# Why won't two views of the same type correctly return the current row?

Tags: c#, acumatica

On a custom screen, I have two ***identical*** views defined like this:

```
    public PXSelectJoin<MXMix,
                    InnerJoin<MXBatch, On<MXBatch.batchID, Equal<MXMix.batchID>>,
                    InnerJoin<SOLine, On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<MXBatch.sOOrderType>,
                                     And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<MXBatch.sOOrderNbr>,
                                     And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<MXBatch.sOLineNbr>>>>,
                    InnerJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<SOLine.customerID>>,
                    LeftJoin<Address, On<Address.addressID, Equal<Customer.defAddressID>>,
                    LeftJoin<INLocation, On<INLocation.locationID, Equal<MXMix.locationID>>>>>>>> MixesBlk;
    
    public PXSelectJoin<MXMix,
                    InnerJoin<MXBatch, On<MXBatch.batchID, Equal<MXMix.batchID>>,
                    InnerJoin<SOLine, On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<MXBatch.sOOrderType>,
                                     And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<MXBatch.sOOrderNbr>,
                                     And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<MXBatch.sOLineNbr>>>>,
                    InnerJoin<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<SOLine.customerID>>,
                    LeftJoin<Address, On<Address.addressID, Equal<Customer.defAddressID>>,
                    LeftJoin<INLocation, On<INLocation.locationID, Equal<MXMix.locationID>>>>>>>> MixesBag;
```

(For what it's worth, the page primary view is **NOT** of the same type.)

These each have a data view delegate which are also ***identical*** except for one condition which separates `bags` from `bulk`.

These views are tied to two separate data grids, which correctly display the records matching the data view delegate conditions (fig 1).

[image]

The issue is, when I attempt to get the selected row from either grid, it simply returns the first row from the database regardless of the data view delegate conditions.

Also, I have `SyncPosition` enabled on both grids.

Am I doing something incorrectly, or is this somehow a limitation in Acumatica?

Comment: I managed to get result I needed by extending the ``MXMix`` class to two empty classes: ``MXMixBag`` and ``MXMixBlk``.  Using these types in my views returns the selected item correctly.  Seems like an Acumatica limitation, but I would still welcome an official response.

Comment: You don't use **Current** to connect these views specifically to the primary view of the graph.  Therefore, and possibly intentionally, these views should return every record in the database that fits your join and where clauses.  Typically, I would expect to see *Where [some key field] = Current key field of the primary DAC* and possibly each view having another field that differentiates if it is a bag or blk.  As separate views, they each could point to a different record when referencing Current because they would just be the current one you have clicked on in a grid, for example.

Comment: As it is written, I'd expect MixBlk.Current and MixBag.Current to be the same until you interact with the data control that is using them.  Also, note that using Current to reference a DAC will not be the same as using ViewName.Current.  They will be competing with each other for Current DAC record whereas the views can easily have a different Current record, depending on your control that leverages them (form or grid).

Comment: @BrianStevens I understand that ViewName.Current won't return the last selected record. I only want the current grid row from that particular grid. It doesn't even give that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Current property of your view actually maps to the Caches dictionary of the graph behind the scenes. Here's how the Current property is implemented on PXSelect:

```
        /// <summary>Gets or sets the <tt>Current</tt> property of the cache that
        /// corresponds to the DAC specified in the type parameter.</summary>
        public virtual Table Current
        {
            get
            {
                return (Table)View.Cache.Current;
            }
            set
            {
                View.Cache.Current = value;
            }
        }
```

And PXView.Cache implementation is:

```
        /// <summary>Gets the cache corresponding to the first DAC mentioned in
        /// the BQL command.</summary>
        public virtual PXCache Cache
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Cache == null || _Graph.stateLoading)
                {
                    _Cache = Graph.Caches[CacheType];
                }
                return _Cache;
            }
        }
```

`MixesBlk.Current` and `MixesBag.Current` are both using the same underlying cache, and retrieving the current property of other view will be equivalent to `Caches[typeof(MXMix)].Current`

The solution you took is the same one I would have used -- by creating an inherited type, you ensure that both views will have a different cache in the graph. You will find this pattern used in a couple of places in Acumatica.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed to know!